# How to get react router methods in HOC component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created on HOC component in my react application to reuse my code and for some purpose I need search params from the query but the `react-router-dom` is not accessible inside it and throwing error.

Here is my HOC component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getOrders } from "../../api/overview-controller";

const OrdersListHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
    const orderListHOCComponent = () => {
        const search = useLocation().search;
        const limit = new URLSearchParams(search).get('limit') || 20;
        const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
        const [customerNumber, setCustomerNumber] = useState("");
        const [subcontractor, setSubcontractor] = useState("");

        useEffect (() => {
            fetchOrders()
        }, []);

        const fetchOrders = async() => {
            const searchFilter = {
                customerNumber,
                subcontractor,
                limit
            }
            const orders = await getOrders(searchFilter);
            setOrders(orders);
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <WrappedComponent orders={orders}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return orderListHOCComponent;
};

export default OrdersListHOC;
```

Here is my order list component

```
const OrdersList = ({ orders }: props) => {
  return (<>
        {orders.map((order) => {
            return (<React.Fragment key={order.order.id}>
            <Grid container justifyContent={"center"} spacing={2}>
                <Grid item>
                    <Typography variant='subtitle1' mb={1/2}>Order number:</Typography>
                    <Typography variant='subtitle1' mb={1/2}>Customer name:</Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <Typography variant='h6'>{order.order.kind}{order.order.location.countryCode}{moment(order.order.orderDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("YY")}/{order.order.id}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant='h6'>{order.order.customerNumber.name}</Typography>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Divider light={false}/>
        </React.Fragment>)})}
  </>);
}

export default OrderListHOC(OrdersList);
```

Error:

```
Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message isn't exactly unclear, the `useLocation` hook can only be used within a routing context, e.g. a router. You just need to ensure there's a router upstream, i.e. higher in the ReactTree than any component that needs it. I'd suggest also using the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook instead of constructing your own `URLSearchParams` object.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getOrders } from "../../api/overview-controller";

const withOrdersList = (WrappedComponent) => (props) => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const limit = searchParams.get('limit') || 20;

  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  const [customerNumber, setCustomerNumber] = useState("");
  const [subcontractor, setSubcontractor] = useState("");

  useEffect (() => {
    const fetchOrders = async () => {
      const searchFilter = {
        customerNumber,
        subcontractor,
        limit
      }
      const orders = await getOrders(searchFilter);
      setOrders(orders);
    }

    fetchOrders();
  }, []);

  return <WrappedComponent {...props} orders={orders} />;
};

export default withOrdersList;
```

```
const OrdersList = ({ orders }: props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {orders.map((order) => (
        <React.Fragment key={order.order.id}>
          <Grid container justifyContent={"center"} spacing={2}>
            <Grid item>
              <Typography variant='subtitle1' mb={1/2}>Order number:</Typography>
              <Typography variant='subtitle1' mb={1/2}>Customer name:</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Typography variant='h6'>
                {order.order.kind}{order.order.location.countryCode}
                {moment(order.order.orderDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("YY")}/{order.order.id}
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant='h6'>{order.order.customerNumber.name}</Typography>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Divider light={false} />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default withOrderList(OrdersList);
```

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import OrderList from '../path/to/OrderList';

...

<BrowserRouter> // <-- provide routing context to sub-Reactree
  ...

  <div>
    <OrderList /> // <-- can access routing context
  </div>

  ...
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I almost cried :-(. Thanks a ton sir... But why we can use `useSearchParams` and not the `useLocation`? I thought we could not use any of the method from the `react-router-dom`

Comment: @Profer Either will work. Using the `useSearchParams` hook directly is less work/code for you than using the `useLocation` hook, getting the `location.search` string, passing it to the `URLSeachParams` constructor, etc. Imagine if you had several query params to access. It's also what the `useSearchParams` hook is specifically for, getting and setting the queryString params.

Comment: I am still getting the same error `Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
` I have my order list inside browser context

Comment: @Profer So long as the `useLocation` hook is called in a function component within a routing context is should be fine. Can you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Comment: Sorry it is working fine thanks

Comment: One last thing it is possible to get all the key value pair and set in state at once because just like `limit` I have 20 fields in the query string? `const limit = searchParams.get('limit') || 20;
`

Comment: @Profer I'm not sure why you'd duplicate the search params into local state, but the `searchParams` object is a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object that has a few methods that return iterators that you could loop over and get the key-value pairs for storing locally in state. There are examples in the linked documentation. Instead of storing these in `useState` and using `useEffect` to "synchronize" I'd suggest using the `useMemo` hook to "unpack" and memoize the params.